# How do I create a power automate workflow for Sharepoint Paige approvals?

Tags: workflow, power-automate, approval-process

I’m quite new to power automate, and the following requirements is what I need to achieve, and it’s all quite tricky to understand at my early stage.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to construct a workflow for the following:

Sharepoint Page Approvals Process (some manual – some automated)

1. Sharepoint Site owner (Jane) manually create a Site Page
2. Site Owner (Jane) either publishes page directly OR submits page to a Content Author (Mary) to add content/populate.
3. Content Author (Mary) makes all changes and adds to the page and submits to a Content Owner (Alex) for approval/decline.
4. Content Author (Alex) either approved, submitting it back to Site Owner (Jane) OR declines and sends back to content Author (Mary) for further edits.
5. Site Owner reviews content and either send back to Content Author or publishes the page (manual).
6. When a page is published by the site owner, the Content Author and Content Owner receive an automated notificacton.

Any help would be so appreciated!